# Inexplicable Segmentation fault:11

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I have this code below to implement maximum subsequence length searching. I couldn't check if the program is right or not since running my program produces segmentation faults.

The program compiles fine.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int a[6]={1,-2,4,33,0,-6};      //THE ACTUAL SEQUENCE
   int count_a[6]={1,1,1,1,1,1};   //ARRAY TO KEEP COUNT OF MAXIMUM LENGTHS FROM POINT OF VIEW OF EACH ELEMENT OF ARRAY A
   int i=0;
   int j=0;
   int k=0;
   for(k=1;k<6;k++)
   {
      j=k;
      printf("k's value:%d\t",j);   //JUST FOR TESTING
      while(1)
      {
         if(a[i]<a[j])
         {
             if(count_a[j]<(1+count_a[i]))
             {
                count_a[j]=1+count_a[i];
             }
         }
         if(j-1==1)
         {
             break;
         }
         else
         {
             i++;
         }
     }
     i=0;
   }


   /* THIS IS FOR ME TO CHECK WHETHER THE LENGTH VALUES HAVE BEEN UPDATED IN THE COUNT_A ARRAY*/
   for(k=0;k<6;k++)
   {
       printf("%d\t",count_a[k]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're getting a segmentation fault when you compile?  you never get to run your code?  what compiler are you using?

Comment: I am compiling it in Mac...using this command:
    gcc test.c -o test.out

Comment: Your code is incomplete as shown.  There's no closing } for main().  Might be what's causing the seg fault, but ... if so ... wow, that's a bad compiler

Comment: sorry, somehow the '}' came in the text area. The closing curly brace exists in the main program!

Comment: Are you sure to start loop from `1` here `for(k=1;k<6;k++)`. On the previous line it is wtitten `int k=0;`.

Comment: @IvanGritsenko  Yes I would like to start the loop from 1.

Comment: It wouldn't be particularly inexplicable if this program crashed, with its obvious out-of-bounds access. But since you're sure it's the compiler that is segfaulting, it is indeed quite inexplicable.

Comment: @EOF I tried online compilers also, they are also throwing segmentation faults

Comment: @MichaelPetch yes. After entering this command in the terminal, it segfaults.   gcc test.c -o test.out

Comment: @SriHariVignesh: Have you considered filing a bugreport for these compilers? It's quite rare for a compiler to just segfault.

Comment: Just to clarify, the compiler does not segfault, the program does. It gets an out of bounds error on line 20 `if(a[i]<a[j])`

Comment: @JoshdeKock please tell me why the printf statement in line 17 is not getting printed then

Comment: I think you are mistaken about the compiler segfaulting.  It compiles OK for me.  Have you tried running in the debugger? Or adding some printfs?

Comment: @MichaelPetch yes. Thats what I do. Sorry for not mentioning it. After gcc test.c -o test.out, I run ./test.out. It segfaults after that

Comment: @SriHariVignesh: You are aware that stdout is buffered?

Comment: You should change the \t to \n on line 17

Comment: @bruceg Sorry, I meant that the program exits giving a segfault message. Sorry for saying it segfaults while compiling. I will edit the post

Comment: You are having infinite loop. `j=k;` then `while(1)` can only terminate when `if(j-1==1)`. On the first iteration `k` is set to 1 so `j` is also set to `1`. Never breaks because `1-1!=1`.

Comment: @IvanGritsenko thank you very much. That solved the problem. '1' and 'i' looked very similar to me. I rewrote the code a few times and must have replaced '1' with 'i'. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not clear that any basic debugging has even been attempted.

Comment: @bruceg how would changing '\t' to '\n' remove segfault error?

Comment: It wouldn't.  But, you wouldn't see your output until it includes a "newline".  C will buffer your output in memory until you include the new line.  Since a \t is a tab, and there's no newline that output is lost when your program crashes.

Comment: @bruceg oh i see! I didn't know that. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having infinite loop. `j=k;` then `while(1)` can only terminate when `if(j-1==1)`. On the first iteration `k` is set to `1` so `j` is also set to `1`. Never breaks because `1-1!=1`. Your `j` is never changed inside `while(1)` loop.

`i++` is always the option. When `i` becomes large it tries to read from outside of array `count_a[i]` causing segfault.

Answer (score 2):

Let's use [clang's address sanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) to figure out what is going on:

```
[3:41pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] clang -g -fsanitize=address blah.c
[3:41pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] ./a.out
=================================================================
==22763==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7fff52950958 at pc 0x00010d2b0953 bp 0x7fff52950910 sp 0x7fff52950908
READ of size 4 at 0x7fff52950958 thread T0
    #0 0x10d2b0952 in main blah.c:20
    #1 0x7fff851205ac in start (/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib+0x35ac)
    #2 0x0  (<unknown module>)

Address 0x7fff52950958 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 56 in frame
    #0 0x10d2b072f in main blah.c:8

  This frame has 2 object(s):
    [32, 56) 'a' <== Memory access at offset 56 overflows this variable
    [96, 120) 'count_a'
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism or swapcontext
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow blah.c:20 main
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x1fffea52a0d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffea52a0e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffea52a0f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffea52a100: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffea52a110: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x1fffea52a120: 00 00 00 00 f1 f1 f1 f1 00 00 00[f2]f2 f2 f2 f2
  0x1fffea52a130: 00 00 00 f3 f3 f3 f3 f3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffea52a140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffea52a150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffea52a160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffea52a170: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Heap right redzone:      fb
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack partial redzone:   f4
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==22763==ABORTING
k's value:1 Abort
```

So you're accessing beyond the end of `a[]`.

If I reduce your code down, we can see that this is obviously possible:

```
k = 1;
j = k;

while(1)
{
    if(a[i]<a[j])
        if(count_a[j]<(1+count_a[i]))
            count_a[j]=1+count_a[i];
    if(j-1==1)
        break;
    else
        i++;
}
```

Note that `j-1` will **never** equal `1` on this iteration (it will always be `0`), so you will increment `i` until it is well past the end of `a`.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. What I did was a dumb mistake. While retyping some code, I must have entered '1' instead of 'i' and I somehow didn't notice it while reviewing my code.  Will increase font size in my IDE from now on.